# Onchange event of input type=range with external change of this input

Tags: input, html5-audio

professionals!

I'm trying to build html5 audio player. And I can even hard explain what is going on with this player. I have progress bar (max attribute is set via JavaScript):

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="" step="1" value="0" class="progbar_input" onclick="SetProgress(this.value)">
```

And I have JavaScript function:

```
function SetProgress(val) {
    $("#player").prop("currentTime", val);
}
```

Seems like everything ok. Also, while playing music, progress bar should change itself:

```
$("#player").bind('timeupdate', function () {
    var currentTime = $("#player").prop('currentTime');
    $(".progbar_input").val(currentTime);
});
```

But when we combine automatic change and manual change - we get a very strange behavior. If JavaScript can change value in time, just after click - everything ok, but if it can't - automatic change occurs. For example, at some moment we have

```
<input type="range" value="10">
```

And automatically after second it should change to 11. We click on 40. But JavaScript change to 11. Sometimes manual change works, sometimes no and I can't even make a search phrase to Google it, so asking for your help now.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UnR9L/1/

It might be everything ok some clicks, but after 10 clicks in different position you notice bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made hidden input and set it to 1 when MouseDown event occurs on progress bar and set it back to 0 when MouseUp event occurs. And it TimeUpdate event check if this hidden input is 0. If it is 0 - I modify progress bar.